# Unable To Reach Sentry Log Server Error 400

Tags: python, django, sentry

I get the following error when my Sentry client tries logging an error:

```
 Unable to reach Sentry log server: HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST (url: http://localhost:8000/sentry/store/, body: Missing data)
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/home/deploy/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sentry/client/base.py", line 210, in send
           return self.send_remote(url=url, data=message, headers=headers)
         File "/home/deploy/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sentry/client/base.py", line 194, in send_remote
           response = urllib2.urlopen(req, data).read()
         File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
           return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
         File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
           response = meth(req, response)
         File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
           'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
         File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
           return self._call_chain(*args)
         File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
           result = func(*args)
         File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
           raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
       HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST Http 404
```

The error that it is trying to log doesn't get saved to the server.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too.

Have looked into the sentry codebase and found the place where it throws the 400 (line 424 of `web/views.py`)

It happens in the else clause that checks for the header `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`. To get this to be passed through, I had to add `WSGIPassAuthorization On` to my apache conf....

I think the else clause I mention above must have a bug in it, because this should be handled....

Comment: Yes, that worked. An older django-sentry (1.6.2) didn't have the problem connecting to the server, but 1.8.9 had the empty data error when connecting to the very same server. Adding "WSGIPassAuthorization On" to the sentry server's apache conf helped.

Comment: Any idea if it's also affecting Nginx server too?